# awk print to file

Tags: awk

I have a big c file that gives a lot of output that I don't care about right now. I wrote this awk script to do mostly what I want. Not sure how to put the finishing touches on it. I would also like it to write to a file when it gets the appropriate condition as true. Is this possible with awk? Or do I need to use a different program?

```
./a.out 50 5 4 | 
awk '{
if ($1 =="success")
    {
    print "success";
    print $3;
    //write to success file
    }
if ($1 =="failure")
    {
    print "failure";
    print $3;
    //write to failure file
    }
if ($4 =="page")
    print "page";
    //write to page file
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

that could be shorterned to

```
awk '$1 == "success" || $1 == "failure" { print ; print > $1 ".txt" }
     $4 == "page" { print ; print > $4 ".txt" ;} '
```

You can remove print statement if you do no want.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the direction of this?

```
awk '
/^success / { print $0 > "success.txt" }
/^failure / { print $0 > "failure.txt" }
'
```

- Output Statements: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_10

Comment: `$1 == "success" { print > "success.txt" }` would be even better